# Oracle APEX - Multiple Line Styles in the same chart (AnyChart but any charting service will work)

Tags: oracle-apex, anychart

I am currently using Oracle Apex 4.1 to develop a chart (using default AnyChart plug-in) which has multiple series with dynamically populated data from SQL Queries.  While I can easily change the line color for each series, I must also differentiate the lines with different line styles (such as one solid, one dashed, one dashed with diamond markers, etc.)  To the best of my knowledge and attempting to use the Custom XML feature of AnyChart charts, I can not seem to set the line style for each line series.

1) Does anyone have a solution as to how to set the line style for each series by manipulating the CustomXML portion of the APEX builder page?  I do not see a way to split up the #DATA# substitution screen.

2) Does anyone know of another solution I can incorporate into APEX pages to accomplish my goal?  I am not attached to AnyChart in any way.

Thank you for your help.  Below is a google image search of the sort of solutions I am looking for.

http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&tbo=d&biw=1440&bih=799&tbm=isch&tbnid=gel5t-WrO7YnQM:&imgrefurl=http://www.swiftchart.com/example_1.htm&docid=cL4I17cL558p_M&imgurl=http://www.swiftchart.com/line_ex5.png&w=400&h=300&ei=JW6-UO_4C6H62gWK54DoAw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=4&vpy=494&dur=29&hovh=194&hovw=259&tx=79&ty=185&sig=100543309725245412492&page=1&tbnh=139&tbnw=189&start=0&ndsp=26&ved=1t:429,r:20,s:0,i:152

Answer (score 3):

Just for those who will seek an answer for the same questions.

AnyChart allows to apply different styles to chart elements. To do what OP wanted you need to define styles at Custom XML and assign them to series. For example, this is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<anychart>
  <charts>
    <chart plot_type="CategorizedVertical">

      <styles>
        <line_style name="style1">
          <line enabled="True" thickness="4" color="Rgb(86,86,26)" />
          <effects>
            <bevel enabled="true" highlight_opacity="0.4" shadow_opacity="0.4" distance="2" />
            <drop_shadow enabled="true" opacity="0.3" />
          </effects>
          <states>
            <hover>
              <border color="DarkRed" thickness="6" />
            </hover>
          </states>
        </line_style>
        <line_style name="style2" parent="style1">
          <line color="Rgb(180,180,255)" />
        </line_style>
        <line_style name="style3" parent="style1">
          <line color="Rgb(255,170,170)" dashed="True" dash_length="5" space_length="5" />
        </line_style>
      </styles>

      <data_plot_settings default_series_type="Line">
        <line_series>
          <marker_settings enabled="false" />
        </line_series>
      </data_plot_settings>

      <!--#DATA#-->
      &PAGE_ITEM_WITH_CHART_DATA.

      <chart_settings>
        <title enabled="false" />
        <axes>
          <y_axis>
            <title>
              <text>Salary</text>
            </title>
          </y_axis>
          <x_axis>
            <title>
              <text>Month</text>
            </title>
          </x_axis>
        </axes>
      </chart_settings>
    </chart>
  </charts>
</anychart>
```

The hidden `PAGE_ITEM_WITH_CHART_DATA` item should contain all the chart data series. The `styles` element defines different styles to use with the parts of chart. We can assign one of them to the whole series like next:

```
<data>
  <series name="2003 Sales" style="style1">
    <point name="January" y="12000" />
    <point name="February" y="15000" />
    <point name="March" y="16000" />
    <point name="April" y="15000" />
    <point name="May" y="14000" />
  </series>
  ...
</data>
```

Or we can assign a style to just one point:

```
<data>
  ...
  <series name="2004 Sales" style="style2">
    <point name="January" y="10000" />
    <point name="February" y="12000" />
    <point name="March" y="18000" style="style3" />
    <point name="April" y="11000" />
    <point name="May" y="9000" />
  </series>    
<data>
```

You can find an example with the XML code [here](http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/Line-Spline-Step-Line-Chart.html#several_styles).